# Select element doesn't have a default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I created a form with redux-form. It works correctly but if I don't change select (I'll leave the default value), the value won't send, but if I change the value it will be sent in post method.

```
export const mySelect = (props) => {
  const mySelectOptions = (key, index) => {
    return (
      <option key={props.options[key].id} value={props.options[key].id}>
        {props.options[key].name}
      </option>
    );
  };

  if (props && props.options) {
    return (
      <div className="mv3 w-100">
        <div className="b sans-serif pv2 w-100">{props.label}</div>
        <select
          {...props.input}
          className="pa2 input-reset ba b--black-40 w-100"
        >
          {Object.keys(props.options).map(renderSelectOptions)}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <div></div>;
};
```

Example

```
<Field
  name="gender"
  label="gender"
  component={input.mySelect}
  options={[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "male",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "female",
    },
  ]}
/>;
```

I tried to set a default value in my SQL table but every time it sends null. Do you know how can I solve my problem?

Comment: You should set one of the options to have the `selected` attribute in it. Maybe if you change the first element(probably by checking if index is equal to 0) to look like this it should work:
`<option key={props.options[key].id} value={props.options[key].id} selected>`

Comment: I have an error `Use the 'defaultValue' or 'value' props on <select> instead of setting 'selected' on <option>.`